# MONO Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener with intermittent System.MissingMemberException - WHY?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, owin

**Important note... this is on Mono / Linux! Maybe I should have mentioned that before...**

I am busy porting inherited code that creates a local http listener which has, up until very recently, been working fine.

However yesterday we had an issue on one of the two machines that has this code running whereby the service wouldn't start at all on the grounds of a MissingMemberException.

```
The server factory could not be located for the given input: Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
```

As we had been messing with VPNs etc. on that machine we wondered if there was a chance that that had interfered with it, so we went to another machine with the same build on it (which had had no messing around done to it) and that also failed to work with the same error.

Just in case, I recompiled the code again (after updating Nuget packages - which included, interestingly, the Owin stuff) and copied to both machines. Both failed to work.

Hair falling out at this stage we left the machines for a little while, and when we got back one worked and one didn't.

**Exactly the same code on each!**

Eventually left it overnight and both worked, then one did and one didn't... etc. etc.

We have done absolutely nothing substantial to fix it, but I cannot work out what is going on.

The exception implies that it is calling a method somewhere in the httplistener that is either not implemented or not made public.

Other questions in Stack Overflow suggest that maybe the dll isn't there - but clearly it is or it would never work!

Perhaps it is somewhere in the workings of the listener that specific circumstances force it to look for a method that isn't implemented / available?

Could networking issues cause this to happen? If so why? Surely all the requisite comms are local?

Any ideas would be appreciated as I am ageing prematurely as a result of all this!

Stack trace below...

```
> MissingMemberException: The server factory could not be located for
> the given input: Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener   Module
> "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine", line 69, col 0, in
> ResolveServerFactory
>     Void ResolveServerFactory(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext)  
> Module "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine", line 66, col 0,
> in Start
>     System.IDisposable Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext)   Module
> "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter", line 12, col 0,
> in Start
>     System.IDisposable Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)   Module "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter", line 46, col
> 0, in Start
>     System.IDisposable Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)   Module "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp", line 75, col 0, in
> StartImplementation
>     System.IDisposable StartImplementation(System.IServiceProvider, Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)   Module
> "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp", line 20, col 0, in Start
>     System.IDisposable Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)   Module "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp", line 35, col 0, in Start
>     System.IDisposable Start[LocalServerStartup](Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)  
> Module "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp", line 6, col 0, in Start
>     System.IDisposable Start[LocalServerStartup](System.String)
```

Comment: Try to create a stripped down, minimal example, that reproduces the issue (if only one of your machines) and post the code here. At the very least please post the full exception (with stacktrace).

Comment: More likely the entire Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.dll is missing from the published output. No idea why that would be intermittent though, unless there was antivirus or similar locking files.

Comment: @Tratcher Yeah I thought that but dll was definitely there both when working and when not - and hasn't been messed with in between. My thought was that members in the .dll are not implemented in Mono and certain conditions making that noticeable?